# What is difference between DataValueField and DataIdField of DayPilot Scheduler

Tags: asp.net, daypilot, daypilot-scheduler

I am using `DayPilot` which has two attributes `DataValueField` and `DataIdField`. Both are assigned with some values. I can access DataIdField in Code behind using e.Value but cannot access `DataValueField`.

Are these same things or they are different ?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as my other answer:

As seen on this [link](http://www.daypilot.org/api/pro/latest/html/P_DayPilot_Web_Ui_DayPilotCalendar_DataValueField.htm) the `DataValueField` is obsolete:

> Gets or sets the name of the column that contains the id (primary key). Obsolete. Use .DataIdField instead.

In my project I can access the value this way:

```
DataValueField="id" //column "id" of my source table
```

Get it in `BeforeEventRender`:

`string id = (string)e.DataItem["id"];`

Comment: Thanks for the help